# Express: implementing MongoDB session store

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, session

Currently, I am requiring and defining options for `express-session` at the top of `index.js` as follows:

```
const session = require(`express-session`)({
    secret: `MyEpicSecret`,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {maxAge: 1000 * 60} // 1 minute: for testing
}),
```

and I use it with my express app:

```
app.use(session);
```

This layout is important because I later pass `session` to my socket.io module at the bottom of `index.js`:

```
require(`./modules/socket.js`)(server, session);
```

With the above design flow, my app functions as it should and sessions are handled and managed flawlessly. My goal now is to implement `connect-mongo` for saving sessions to a MongoDB. Their [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongo%3E%3Cdocumentation) is a little hazy, but from what I could understand I need to require the `express-session` module first then define the options to use *later* inside `app.use()`. This is an issue - if I define options inside `app.use()` I am no longer able to pass the configured session (it's options) when I require my `socket.js` module.

Would I would *like* to do do is something like:

```
const session = require('express-session')({
    secret: `MyEpicSecret`,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {maxAge: 1000 * 60}, // 1 minute: for testing
    store: new MongoStore(options)
});
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

app.use(session);
```

This is not possible - `MongoStore` is not defined at the time I try to use it. If I move MongoStore *up*, `session` will be undefined when i require MongoStore.

I am still learning the ropes with express and would much appreciate the help that anyone is able to provide :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still assign the result of the `session({...})` call to a variable and pass that around.

```
const expressSession = require('express-session');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(expressSession);

const session = expressSession({
    secret: `MyEpicSecret`,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {maxAge: 1000 * 60}, // 1 minute: for testing
    store: new MongoStore(options)
});

app.use(session);
...
require(`./modules/socket.js`)(server, session);
```

Comment: My understanding on how these particular modules were to be required and used was a little fuzzy. This has assisted me significantly. Thank-you eminently for your help :).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 const session = require('express-session');
 const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

 app.use(session({
    secret: `MyEpicSecret`,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {maxAge: 1000 * 60} // 1 minute: for testing
    store: new MongoStore(options)
 }));
```

Comment: As mentioned in original question, by using this method I am not passing in ``session``'s option object to my ``socket.js`` module when I require it at the bottom of ``index.js``- which is why I must define my options when requiring the module.